# While loading .obj file using libgdx got the error

Tags: android, exception, libgdx, .obj

While loading .obj file using libgdx I got the following error. Can you please tell me what I'm missing here?

```
03-06 15:50:13.901: E/AndroidRuntime(5503): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 9

03-06 15:50:13.901: E/AndroidRuntime(5503): java.lang.NullPointerException at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.tests.Test.create(Test.java:154)

at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:292)

at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1330)

at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1121)

03-06 15:50:13.991: E/SensorManager(5503): unregisterListener:: all sensors,  listener = com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput$SensorListener@4a4e3938

03-06 15:50:13.991: E/SensorManager(5503): unregisterListener:: all sensors,  listener = com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput$SensorListener@4a4e7e80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible you are attempting to access the graphics context before it has been initialised e.g. inside a constructor for your test(s).

Answer (score 0):

Yes... I solved it. There was problem while setting libs files with resources files in a java build path.